# How to shift the first 1/3 of the array?

Tags: arrays, ruby, shift

Is there a way to turn `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` into `[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` in one line?

Right now I plan on assigning it to a variable, getting the length, and using the `shift` function. That works, but I am wondering if there is a more Rubyish way to do it.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
a.shift(a.length/3)
```

Comment: `a.shift(a.length/3)` gives you `[1,2,3]`, not `[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`.

Comment: @Cupcake - but `a` becomes `[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

Comment: @UriAgassi OMG you're right!!! Doh!

Comment: @UriAgassi so does that mean what the original poster has is already pretty much the best way to do this in Ruby?

Comment: @Cupcake, yes I believe he has :-)

Answer (score 1):

Not mutating using [`Array#slice`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-slice)

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
a[(a.length/3)..-1]
#=> [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

An option that mutates and is a one-liner

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].tap { |a| a.shift(a.length/3) }
#=> [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: fyi, `drop` doesn't mutate the original array either.

Comment: My mistake, the original method that the question poster used, `shift`, does mutate the original array, so you were right.

Answer (score 0):

If you apply your code you will get:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
a.shift(a.length/3) # => [1,2,3]
```

but after the operation array `a` will contain that you require:

```
a # => [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

So for example obvious variat to shift is:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
(a.length/3).times {|a| a.shift }
a # => [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Or of course you can just get the required array values as it was denoted by `bjhaid`.